# Why is the a new line in the printf output?

Tags: c, printf

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    char noun[25];
    char plural[28];

    fgets(noun,24,stdin);
    strcpy(plural,noun);
    int len=strlen(plural);

    if(plural[len-2]=='h'||plural[len-2]=='s'){
        plural[len-1]='e';
        plural[len]='s';
        plural[len+1]='\0';
    }else if(plural[len-2]=='y'){
        plural[len-2]='i';
        plural[len-1]='e';
        plural[len]='s';
        plural[len+1]='\0';
    }else{
        plural[len-1]='s';
        plural[len]='\0';
    }

    printf("The plural of noun %s is %s\n",noun,plural);
    return 0;
}
```

the output is always this:

"The plural of noun horse

is horses"

even though i do not put \n the middle of the printf, only in the end.

Comment: So did you read the man-pages of the functions you use? Hint: the answer can be found easily there.

Comment: Hint: What's in `noun`?

Comment: i only technically strcpy(), which doesn't add a new line.

Comment: Your `strcpy` call writes to `plural`, not `noun`.

Comment: thanks Olaf, did a man fgets and found out when you press enter it indents a new line by it self.

Comment: but the reason i used fgets is, i need to limit the input to 25 characters. any ideas

Comment: Technically your current code limits the input to 23 characters (one of which is a `'\n'`).

Comment: Hi, take a look there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input

Comment: You can remove the newline by doing `noun[strcspn(noun, "\n")] = '\0';`.

Comment: thanks a lot, it helped

Comment: @melpomene: That can fail if `noun` doesn't contain a newline, which can happen if `fgets` filled the array before the end of the line.

Comment: @KeithThompson so can i use `scanf("%24s", noun)`, 24 to leave space of `\0`

Comment: @KeithThompson Then it's a no-op.

Comment: @melpomene: You're right, I should have read the doc for `strcspn` before commenting.

Comment: @Andrew: `fgets` reads a line. `scanf` with `%s` reads a sequence of non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fgets is picking up a trailing newline character from stdin when you hit enter. Hence noun ends with a newline char

Comment: thanks you, i did what Olaf said and found that out, any help on how to limit input to 25 characters in scanf. is it this scanf("%25s",noun)